# nodejs cannot find local module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to implement a local library (made for me) but when I try to execute the code the console throws this error:

```
PS C:\Users\dydie\Documents\Proyecto Sena> node src/index.js
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:942
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module './back js/algorithms.js'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\dydie\Documents\Proyecto Sena\src\back js\utilities.js
- C:\Users\dydie\Documents\Proyecto Sena\src\index.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:939:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:780:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\dydie\Documents\Proyecto Sena\src\back js\utilities.js:4:19)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:827:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\dydie\\Documents\\Proyecto Sena\\src\\back js\\utilities.js',
    'C:\\Users\\dydie\\Documents\\Proyecto Sena\\src\\index.js'
  ]
}

Node.js v18.0.0
```

seems that the error comes from this line:

```
const utilities = require("./back js/utilities.js");
```

ironically I before used the same code for other file and it was working (and still working)

what can I do?
I tried to delete and install node_modules and it didn't work.

any idea?
thanks for your atention

Comment: Is your `back js\utilities.js` trying to include `.\back js\algorithms.js`?  (which would be located at `back js\back js\algorithms.js`)

Comment: could be that, but the other code that did work was in the same directory

Comment: Sorry I edited my comment.

Comment: oh don't worry, seeing again your comentary, in fact utilities is trying to call algorithms and I probably  get released about the problem

Comment: yes, that was, I didn't get released that the direction was wrong (I had copied some code from the index file because I wanted to use another file for some functions that I could use in other files)

thanks for your help!! I'm new in stack overflow so can you tell me how to give upvote to comentaries?

Comment: Unrelated, but I recommend against spaces in directory and file names for a variety of reasons, mostly non-technical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `back js/utilities.js` wants to require `algorithms.js` and it's in the same folder as `utilities.js`, then it should `require('./algorithms.js')`, not `require('./back js/algorithms.js')`  Because the path for a require is relative to the file that is executing the `require` command.

`~/index.js` would need `require('./back js/algorithms.js')` to directly require `~/back js/algorithms.js` but
`~/back js/utilities.js` would only need `require('./algorithms.js')` to require `~/back js/algorithms.js`

Note that if `~/back js/utilities.js` wrote `require('./back js/algorithms.js')` then it would be looking for `~/back js/back js/utilities.js`...which is likely not the intended path.